# Is there Any End of Underscores in Numeric Literals?

Tags: java, java-7

I just read Enhancements in Java7(
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).
In that I see Underscores Numeric Literals and try Like....

`int i=9_000;` its OK.

But I see rules for that it also allows like...

```
int i=9____________________________________________________________________________________000;
```

Is there any end of `Underscores`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no limit. Java allows *any* amount of underscores although, depending on how your compiler is implemented, you may run into problems for bizarre edge cases like several billion of them :-)

In those places where you *can* have underscores, the language specification does not limit the quantity. I emphasise "can" there because there are places where they're not allowed, such as before the first digit, after the last, next to the decimal point and so on. But that's a different issue.

However, rather than ask if it's possible, you should instead ask what would be the *point* of more than one consecutive underscore.

One underscore aids readability by naturally grouping the numbers:

```
1_000_000
4072_1199_6645_1234
```

whereas more than one tends to *reduce* readability:

```
1_0_0________000_0
4072___________________________11_9_9_6641234
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no limit. Why should there be ? On the other hand, the only reason I see to use any number of underscores, is to be able to do fancy stuff like in the following piece of code (created by Joshua Bloch, if I'm not mistaken):

```
private static final int BOND =
     0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
   00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+
  000____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+
 000______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+
0000______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+
0000______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+
0000______0000___0000______0000_________0000__0000000000+
0000______0000___0000______0000________0000+
 000______000_____000______000________0000+
  000____000_______000____000_______00000+
   00000000_________00000000_______0000000+
     0000_____________0000________000000007;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the definition of a decimal literal from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10):

```
DecimalNumeral:
    0
    NonZeroDigit Digitsopt
    NonZeroDigit Underscores Digits 

Digits:
    Digit
    Digit DigitsAndUnderscoresopt Digit 

Digit:
    0
    NonZeroDigit

NonZeroDigit: one of
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

DigitsAndUnderscores:
    DigitOrUnderscore
    DigitsAndUnderscores DigitOrUnderscore 

DigitOrUnderscore:
    Digit
    _

Underscores:
    _
    Underscores _
```

Notice the recursive definition for `Underscores`, fun!

Answer (score 2):

No. Here is the document:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal.